# An estimator for inverse of variance

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, parameter-estimation

I want to find some function $f$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X) \right] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2},
$$
where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.
Obviously, $f$ should not depend on $\sigma$.
$1/\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is not what I want.

**Notes**

For a normal random variable, $\mathbb{E}[1/X^2]$ does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that you would get an estimate of $1/\sigma^2$ based on a single observation. Instead, assume that we have $n$ iid observations, $X_1, \dots, X_n.$ Define $S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2.$ It is known that $S^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_n.$ Using the pdf of $\chi^2_n,$ you can show that $$\mathbb{E}(S^{2r}) = \sigma^{2r}\times \frac{\Gamma(n/2+r)}{2^r \Gamma(n/2)}.$$ Set $r=-1$ and get the desired estimator (works for $n>2$).

Comment: I don't think your expression for the expectation works for $r$ negative (at least $r\le -1/2$). Recall that $E(1/X)$ diverges.

Comment: Also, you can get _some_ information about $\sigma$ from a single observation $X$.  Recall that $E|X|=\sigma^2/\sqrt{2\pi}$, or even the $n=1$ case of your estimator.  Of course this is not an unbiased estimator of $1/\sigma^2$, as the OP asked for.

Comment: @Dedekind Cuts, the estimator I gave for $r=-1$ works fine for any $n>2.$ Of course if $n=1$ then $\Gamma(n/2+r)$ would exist (read converge) only for $r>-1/2.$

Comment: Agreed it works for $n>2$.  Maybe add that to your answer?

Comment: So is it impossible to get $1/\sigma^2$ only one observation $X$? Or $1/\sigma$ would be fine. Sadly, your solution is hard to apply my statistical model.